# Trigger Azure DevOps web hook's on bug description change

Tags: azure-devops

I'm configuring a web hook to make a POST when tasks of type bug are changed in a project. I'd like Azure to make the POST only when the description of the bug changes, but I'm not seeing this option on the config modal
[image]

Is it possible to make this configuration? Is there any other field that's equivalent to the Discussion field?

Comment: Do you want it to trigger on the *Description* field, or the *Discussion* field? Your question seems to use both interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default setting, the Bug work item only contains a discussion field.

Based on your requirement, it seems that you want to trigger the web hook when Discussion field update.

On the backend, the **discussion** field is equal to **System.History**。

So you can set the **History** field in Webhook.

For example:

[image]

Then when you update the Discusstion field, it will trigger webhook.